# How do I retrieve the row data from my Django database as a list?

Tags: python, mysql, django, excel, django-queryset

I would like to retrieve the data in my Django database table rows as a list so I can iterate over it and write each value of the list to an Excel spreadsheet. I tried doing this using dictionaries but dictionaries are not ordered in Python so my columns were getting all out of order. I need my Excel spreadsheet to look the same as my database table, not scrambled around in random order. How can I achieve this?

Current code:

```
def dump_attorneys_to_xlsx(request):
    if request.GET.get('export'):
        output = BytesIO()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Summary')

        attorneys = Attorney.objects.all().values()
        # Write header
        worksheet.write_row(0, 0, attorneys[0].keys())
        # Write data
        for row_index, row_dict in enumerate(attorneys, start=1):
            worksheet.write_row(row_index, 0, row_dict.values())
        workbook.close()

        output.seek(0)

        response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=summary.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) object which can take a list of dictionaries instead of lists, or use the QuerySet's [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values) method instead of `values` to return a list of rows instead of dictionaries.

---

Otherwise, you can order the writing to the file with the following (not very performant):

```
keys = attorneys[0].keys()
worksheet.write_row(0, 0, keys)
# Write data
for row_index, row_dict in enumerate(attorneys, start=1):
    row = [row_dict[k] for k in keys]
    worksheet.write_row(row_index, 0, row)
```